# Perfect Forwarding - question about const and non-const ref

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Look at this article http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html. 
We can find there this sentence:

> Firstly, if factory had not one, but several arguments, you would have to provide overloads for all combinations of non-const and const reference for the various arguments.

My question is, why we need to provide overload for combination of non-const and const reference? In my opinion, we need to provide overload only for const references, because we can pass both of rvalues and lvalues to a const reference.

Comment: But if you take a `const` reference, you can't apply it to constructing an object that expects a non-`const` reference as argument.

Answer (score 1):

If the function you are forwarding to takes a const, then you need to pass a const reference.  If the value you are forwarding is a non-const, then you need to pass a non-const, because you will need to forward to the non-const function.